# Python re.sub, re.split fails splitting up words in long passage

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a list of words from an HTML doc stored on disc. When I try to split up the words and add them to my word vector I end up with a mess.

```
 def get_word_vector(self):
  line = self.soup.get_text()
  re.sub("s/(\\u[a-e0-9][a-e0-9][a-e0-9]//|\\n)","",line)
  for word in line.split("\s+"):
   for the_word in word.split("[,.\"\\/?!@#$%^&*\{\}\[\]]+"):
    if the_word not in self.word_vector:
     self.word_vector[the_word]=0
    self.word_vector[the_word]+=1
    self.doc_length=self.doc_length+1
  for keys in self.word_vector:
   print "%r: %r" % (keys, self.word_vector[keys]) #So I can see whats happening
```

When testing this on a wiki page I got (small sample):

```
"Horse Markings"\n"Horse and Pony Head Markings"\n"Horse and Pony Leg Markings"\n"Identifying Horse parts and markings," Adapted From: Horses For Dummies, 2nd Edition.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n[hide]
```

as a single "word". the doc is getting read to BS4 like:

```
  self.soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath,"r"))
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I guess the regex is failing because its wrong???

Comment: So, basically, you need to get a list of words for a web page, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an alternative option: get the text via [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) and then use [`nltk.tokenize`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) to get the list of words from the text. The point here is not to reinvent the wheel and use the specialized tools for specific jobs: `BeautifulSoup` for HTML parsing, `nltk` for text processing:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow'))
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
print tokenizer.tokenize(soup.get_text())
```

prints:

```
[u'Stack', u'Overflow', u'Wikipedia', u'the', u'free', u'encyclopedia', ... ]
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I guess if someone literally made a library for this purpose it would be dumb to ask how to do it. But did you see anything about my regexes that looked wrong?

Comment: @jasondancks well, at least, the `re.sub()` call doesn't modify the string in place, you need to assign the result of it to `line`.

Comment: @jasondancks plus, instead of `line.split()`, you should have used `re.split()`.